# Microsoft Graph CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, microsoft-graph-api

Im using the

> @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client

npm graph package with meteor

I can successfully login, and i have the correct accessToken

But when i make a query, i get the error above. I can't see why this is happening.

```
console.log(microsoft.accessToken)

    // Initialize Graph client
    const client = graph.Client.init({
        authProvider: (done) => {
            done(null, microsoft.accessToken);
        },
        debugLogging: true
    });


    client
        .api('/me')
        .get()
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the access token and how have you confirmed that it is in fact "correct"?